# use "they" to refer one thing

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, pronouns

As you see in this example of online Cambridge dictionary,"they" is used to refer "a porsche". How can it possible?

[image]

Comment: In the Cambridge sentence, _they_ refers to all (new) Porches, not just the one the speaker wants to buy.

Comment: To add on to J.R.'s comment, "it costs an arm and a leg" would imply that this one particular Porsche is very expensive, but using "they" establishes that Porsches as a group are always expensive.

Comment: The key to this sentence is when they use ***a** Porsche* which indicates they are referring to a class i.e. all Porsches.  Had they said *this Porsche* it would have been better the use *it costs an arm and a leg*.